# Program flow and correctly returning control to main() in a safe and eloquent way

Tags: c++

The entry point to my application is here:

```
int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    MainLoop::Start();
    return 0;
}
```

This calls the init function which declares allocates resources and so on.

After initialization, my main loop is thus:

```
void MainLoop::RunLoop(){
    while(1){
        switch(programState){
            case MainLoop::Uninitialized:{
                break;
            }
            case MainLoop::RunningGame:{
                MainLoop::RunGame();
                break;
            }
            case MainLoop::Exiting:{
                MainLoop::ExitSafely();
                break;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

The `MainLoop::ExitSafely()` function performs some garbage collection and makes sure the initialized subsystems have shutdown properly.

The return statement at the end of the loop hands program flow back to the `main()` function, which behaves exactly as expected. I don't like it though.

Maybe my exit function should return `true` and terminate the loop?

This is a personal project, but I'd like to do things properly and what I have just doesn't 'feel' right.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Side note: Your `RunLoop` can be rewritten (optimized), so it doesn't include a `while` loop. at all, due to the location of `return` statement (loop body executes exactly once). Not sure if that is what you intended.

Comment: Looks good to me. Whats the reason you don't like it or have second thoughts about the implementation?

Comment: I see.  Yes, good pickup!  However, in time my application will have more states such as MainLoop::ShowingSplash and MainLoop::ShowingMenu etc.  It will need to loop -this is a minimal example.

Comment: @krizajb Honestly -it's just intuition.  I don't like the while(1) syntax for reasons I have trouble articulating except to say I've never seen it in a book.  I've always seen sentinel values used to exit loops but that seems cumbersome e.g. adding another variable to the MainLoop::RunLoop() function.

Comment: Well usually you use conditional variables and stuff like that if you run the application in multiple threads. While(1) is perfectly normal ... I mean, it exists for a reason :)

Comment: Thanks!  I guess sometimes we just need some positive reinforcement :)

Comment: If you like, you could have an additional state and get `while (programState  != MainLoop::ShutdownComplete)`

Comment: That seems nice.  It's readable which is what I am after -to me that's the most important thing about code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you [Bo Persson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597607/bo-persson) for your contribution.  The suggested solution is readable and functional:

```
void MainLoop::RunLoop(){
    while(programState != MainLoop::Shutdown){
        switch(programState){
            case MainLoop::Uninitialized:{
                break;
            }
            case MainLoop::RunningGame:{
                MainLoop::RunGame();
                break;
            }
            case MainLoop::Exiting:{
                MainLoop::ExitSafely();
                programState = MainLoop::Shutdown;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```